# Backendless Android studio data retrieval not showing in ListView

Tags: listview, android-studio, backendless

I have a database set up in Backendless and my Android Studio application is accessing it. The connection is successful and the names of the items are successfully retrieved (as per the log) but my list view is not showing them. I added an entry "test" locally and this is being shown. Can you help? Here is my code:

```
public class ListItems extends Activity {

ListView foodListView;
ArrayList<String> myFood;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set up listView
    setContentView(R.layout.list_items);
    foodListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.foodListView);
    myFood = new ArrayList();
    myFood.add("test");

    //connect to database
    Backendless.setUrl(Defaults.SERVER_URL);
    Backendless.initApp(getApplicationContext(),
            Defaults.APPLICATION_ID,
            Defaults.API_KEY);

    final IDataStore<Map> tableQuery = Backendless.Data.of( "FoodList" );
    final DataQueryBuilder queryBuilder = DataQueryBuilder.create();

    queryBuilder.setWhereClause( "Section = 'Dairy'" );
    queryBuilder.setSortBy( "name" );

    Backendless.Data.of( "FoodList" ).find( queryBuilder,
            new AsyncCallback<List<Map>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleResponse(List<Map>response ){

                    Iterator<Map> itr = response.iterator();

                    while(itr.hasNext()) {
                        Map<String, Object> contact = (Map<String, Object>) itr.next();
                        String name = (String) contact.get("Name");
                        myFood.add(name);
                    }

                    //test to show items retrived
                    for(String aa:myFood){
                        System.out.println("MYAPP " +aa);
                    }


                }
                @Override
                public void handleFault( BackendlessFault fault )
                {
                    Log.e("MYAPP", "Server reported an error - " + fault.getMessage());
                }
            });


    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myFood);
    foodListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


}
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19043140/1813669

Comment: I tried arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but it doesn't work I am still only getting a list showing "test". is it to do with the retrieving of the data not being complete by the time I set my view?

Comment: It definitely is. Where do you call `.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in responding. I called .notifyDataSetChanged() before and after  foodListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter) but neither seemed to work. Am I doing it in the wrong place?

Comment: You should call in right after the data is updated, which in your case is inside of `handleResponse` method.

Comment: Brilliant, it works! I moved the 'ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter' and 'setAdapter' code into the 'handleResponse' method too. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Great, glad for you. I've added a full response so that it might be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're loading data asynchronously, your `ListView` may be displayed earlier than the data has arrived - thus you won't see it there. To tackle this you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on a `ListView` right after you've updated the data source list, which is inside of `handleResponse` method.

So your code should look like the following:

```
public class ListItems extends Activity {

ListView foodListView;
ArrayList<String> myFood;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set up listView
    setContentView(R.layout.list_items);
    foodListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.foodListView);
    myFood = new ArrayList();

    //connect to database
    Backendless.setUrl(Defaults.SERVER_URL);
    Backendless.initApp(getApplicationContext(), Defaults.APPLICATION_ID, Defaults.API_KEY);

    final IDataStore<Map> tableQuery = Backendless.Data.of( "FoodList" );
    final DataQueryBuilder queryBuilder = DataQueryBuilder.create();

    queryBuilder.setWhereClause( "Section = 'Dairy'" );
    queryBuilder.setSortBy( "name" );

    Backendless.Data.of( "FoodList" ).find( queryBuilder,
            new AsyncCallback<List<Map>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleResponse(List<Map>response ){

                    Iterator<Map> itr = response.iterator();

                    while(itr.hasNext()) {
                        Map<String, Object> contact = (Map<String, Object>) itr.next();
                        String name = (String) contact.get("Name");
                        myFood.add(name);
                    }

                    // new data has been now added to the list - need to update view
                    foodListView.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                @Override
                public void handleFault( BackendlessFault fault )
                {
                    Log.e("MYAPP", "Server reported an error - " + fault.getMessage());
                }
            });


    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myFood);
    foodListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


}
```